# Magento 2 - Which is faster - load product by ID via ProductRepositoryInterface, ProductFactory or object manager

Tags: magento2, performance

Approaching loading products from performance point of view.  Assuming you want to echo out standard attribute values such as SKU, name, etc. and you are dealing with a large number of products and you are loading them within a loop (assume not a product collection). Anyone know which is the fastest method?

**ObjectManager** (Yes I know you're not *supposed* to use this method)

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
```

**ProductRepositoryInterface**

```
protected $productRepository; 
    ...
    public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        ...
        $this->productRepository= $productRepository;
        ...
    }
```

```
    $product = $this->productRepository->getById($id);
```

**ProductFactory**

```
protected $productFactory;  
    ...
    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        ...
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        ...
    }
```

```
$product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($id);
```

Comment: I'm assuming Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository::getById is the same speed if not slower as extends from ProductRepositoryInterface.  But could be wrong?

Comment: Don't use $this->productFactory->create()->load($id);, this load method is deprecated.

Comment: \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository::getById has caching.  Anyone know whether this or \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::getById  is the prefered method?

Comment: \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::getById  -> This is prefered method.

Comment: Okay so preferred methods aside - Is it faster?

Comment: Yes, it is. It has param like $editMode, if you pass this false which is faster. If you need more product then use getList method.

Comment: What about $forceReload param? Any faster? Is any of this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario we can compare only two option **ProductRepositoryInterface**
and **Product Factory**. So these two options the **ProductRepositoryInterface** is faster then **Product Factory** the reason behind that is **ProductRepositoryInterface** is getting the Data using **API**

Comment: Do you have any stats to support this?

Comment: \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface is very slow and using lots of memory.